# Search a object without iterating a collection in java

Tags: java

How to look for a particular object in a large list(java collection) without iterating it. Assume we have a large collection and just need to check whether a object exists or not without iterating.

Comment: Why would you need not iterate? Is this a puzzle?

Comment: It seems that you have very poor imagination of structures representation in computer.

Comment: no actually my collection is very large and iterating through and comparing may delayed the response ..!

Comment: We don't really know about your problem. You should include some code and specify the approximate size of the collection in question.

Comment: ok will publish the code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, Let's step out of the binary world.

Think of a chest full of Lego parts. You want a 2x2 flat black piece.
How would you find it without looking in the chest?
There is no magical to find it, you need to jump into the chest and find the piece grabbing one by one and checking if it's the one you are looking for.

There are ways to speed up the process.
You can **Organise** (sort your collection) by colour for example and just look in the black pile.

Or you can **map** (Index your pieces) so you know the position of the piece and can go and retrieve from you know where the piece is.

That is, in a very simplistic way, the same idea for databases and collection.

So, summarizing, no, you can't not just find without looking. Sorry :(